# Conditional Drop-down Redirect with Cookies

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, cookies, dropdown

We have a ongoing wordpress radio website build that involves the user selecting their region and state via conditional drop-down section and there will be a submit button that redirects them to the page containing specific content for that location.

Here's the HTML code of the conditional drop-down

```
<form id="location" name="location">
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
                <select name="region" id="region">
                    <option value="">Select Your Region</option>
                    <option value="queensland">Queensland</option>
                    <option value="new_south_wales">New South Wales</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">
                <select disabled="disabled" id="state" name="state">
                    <option value>Select State</option>
                    <!-- Queensland -->
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Beaudesert - 92.1 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Biloela - 89.7 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Canungra - 88.9 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Chinchilla - 95.5 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Cooktown - 92.1 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Gold Coast - 100.6 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Goondiwindi - 98.7 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Logan - 92.1 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Miles - 101.3 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Monto - 100.5 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Richmond - 104.5 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Stanthorpe - 90.1 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Taroom - 94.1 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Theodore - 99.5 FM</option>
                    <option rel="queensland" value="">Weipa - 97.7 FM</option>

                    <!-- New South Wales -->
                    <option rel="new_south_wales" value="">Bourke - 107.3 FM</option>
                    <option rel="new_south_wales" value="">Gloucester - 97.7 FM</option>
                    <option rel="new_south_wales" value="">Tenterfield - 102.5 FM</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="submit_button"><a id="submit-btn" href="https://website.com/">Submit</a></div>
```

Here's the Javascript for the conditional functionality and redirect

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var $cat = $("#region"),
            $subcat = $("#state");

        $cat.on("change",function(){
            var _rel = $(this).val();
            $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
            $subcat.val("");
            if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
            $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
            $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
        });

    });
</script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("location").onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("submit-btn").href = "https://website.com/"+this.value+"/";
    }
</script>
```

I would like to ask how to implement some cookies so that when the user goes back to website, the last visited location page will be loaded. Any help regarding this one will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a question.
Why you use it

```
document.getElementById("location").onchange
```

I think you need to set event change for select.

When the user goes back to website, If you want the last visited location page will be loaded, you need to save value of select into cache

You can use localStorage.

When user change select, 
we use localStorage to save data into cache.

When user goes back to website, we get data from cache and set for select